# Error Artifact Glassfish con IntelliJ IDEA JAVA JSF

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, glassfish, intellij-idea

> [2018-05-07 11:19:12,145] **Artifact DemoJSF:war exploded: Artifact is
>   being deployed, please wait...**
>
> [2018-05-07 11:19:17,472] **Artifact DemoJSF:war exploded: Error
>   during artifact deployment. See server log for details.**
>
> **Critical error during deployment:**  javax.faces.FacesException:
>   Unable to find CDI BeanManager    at
>   com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.tryAddCDIELResolver(ELUtils.java:312)    at
>   com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:242)     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:499)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.performOneTimeELInitialization(ApplicationImpl.java:1404)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:526)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5043)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:592)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5612)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:540)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:900)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2044)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1690)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
>   Startup of context /DemoJSF_war_exploded failed due to previous
>   errors]]
>
> [2018-05-07T11:19:17.424-0500] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE]
>   [AS-WEB-CORE-00175] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=47
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1525709957424] [levelValue: 1000] [[   Exception during cleanup after start failed
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Manager has not yet been
>   started   at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5817)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:569)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5630)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:540)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:900)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2044)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1690)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Explica mas como te sucede el error

Comment: ahi  edite la pregunta esta la imagen

Comment: puedes editar la pregunta y mostrar el pom porque error dice que no has cargado el **CDI**